# get latest specific project in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, tfs

I have a project that should be get latest to specific date. I have this code:

```
            var serverFolder = pathInTfs;
            var localFolder = pathInLocalMachin;
            var workingFolder = new WorkingFolder(serverFolder, localFolder);
            // Create a workspace mapping
            workspace.CreateMapping(workingFolder);

            if (!workspace.HasReadPermission)
            {
                throw new SecurityException(
                    String.Format("{0} does not have read permission for {1}",
                                  versionControl.AuthorizedUser, serverFolder));
            }
            // Get the files from the repository
             workspace.Get(dateForLatest, GetOptions.Overwrite);
```

every thing is good but I want to be get latest only directory "pathInTfs" in "pathInLocalMachin" but when program run workspace.Get() every project be get latest.
How I can get latest one path in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several overloads of `Get` which allow you to specify the set of objects you want to get. For what you're doing, I think you want [`Get(GetRequest, GetOptions)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb139308%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

The `GetRequest` includes an `ItemSpec` where you can specify a folder to get, and then indicate `RecursionType.Full`.